# How to merge multiple app.config files on runtime in .net?

Tags: .net, app-config

With web apps, multiple web.config files are merged based on the directory hierarchy. Is there a way to define a custom hierarchy for regular windows apps? The functionality for config file merging already exists, so I don't see why it shouldn't be possible.

Currently the hierarchy is `user.config -> roaming.config -> app.config -> machine.config`. And there are huge restrictions on what can go into user.config and roaming.config.

I would like to be able to have the following hierarchy: `additional2.config -> additional1config -> app.config -> machine.config`, or as many config files as I want, resulting in a single `Configuration` object that I can read from. Otherwise, I would have to search each additional config manually.

`configSource` is not enough for me, because it could be that the additional configuration files contains new config sections.

Comment: Still a good question.